# .htaccess - match subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this should be very easy, but still

I need to have the following URL options:

1. domain.com
2. domain.com/page/1234
3. domain.com/someWords-MoreWords
4. domain.com/buylink/1234

   - N1 and N2 needs to go to --> index.php
   - N3 --> second.php
   - N4 --> third.php

the following works for N1 and N2, but could not make **N3** work.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule page/([0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?) index.php?&page=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try (did not test it):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?&page=$1 [L,S=2]
RewriteRule ^buylink/([0-9]+)/?$ third.php?&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ second.php?&page=$1 [L]
```

**Update *added flag S* (thanks to @Prix):**

The `S` flag will skip the conditions for the next 2 rules too

Comment: The 2 conditions should be on attached to the last rule, right now they are on the first which doesn't really need it.

Comment: it's needed for all three rules, but thank you, I've updated answer

Comment: It's not and even if it was you would need to append it 3 times with your previous rule as you have a last flag per RewriteRule. *page and buylink are exact matches which is why you don't need to check for folder and directory whereas the last rule is more general at the root which is why you need to check it.*

Comment: yes right, it's not needed in this case, but spoils nothing, even for the future if you somehow may need to include `.` too that will not bang redirect loop. also no need for duplicating those lines

Comment: thanks a lot for input. last one has some issues - it handles some direct link to php file: RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ second.php?&page=$1 [L]  handles this link: http://macbook-pro.local/image/?testParam

Comment: you can remove `/?` this two symbols so `^([\w-]+)$` would work